# How to access External DB from kubernate pods

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, kubernetes-pod

I deployed the dotnet core application using the connection string. I couldn't access external DB after I deploy the dotnet core app in Kubernetes Pods.

The site shows below error:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to
>   SQL Server)

Can you please help me?

[image]

Comment: Is your database accessible from your Kubernetes cluster? Typically you might have to do firewall/route table config. Where is your DB / Kubernetes cluster located?

Comment: are you trying to connect to an azure sql db?

Comment: Check also you don't have applied _NetworkPolicy_ `egress` policies that block all the external traffic to your Pod(s) residing in your Namespace

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi  Linux Server(Kubernetes deployed in Linux server)(192.168.1.112) and SQL DB(192.168.12.179) is located in the same network only.

Comment: Are you able to access the DB from servers other than Kubernetes located in the same network? From the pod in the Kubernetes cluster are you able to connect to the outside world? for example `curl https://example.com`

Comment: @MarkusDresch No, I am connecting same network DB only

Comment: @TummalaDhanvi Ya, I can accessible